# Pass volume mounts as an external file (docker-compose)

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose.yml file like this:

```
  name:
    image: docker/container
    container_name: coolcontainer
    restart: always

    volumes:
      - ${DIR1PATH}:/storage/${DIR1}
      - ${DIR2PATH}:/storage/${DIR2}
      - ${DIR3PATH}:/storage/${DIR3}
      - ${DIR4PATH}:/storage/${DIR4}
```

Is it possible to store all the volume mounts in a separate file so that the docker-compose.yml can be replaced with:

```
  name:
    image: docker/container
    container_name: coolcontainer
    restart: always

    volumes:
      ${CUSTOM_MOUNTS_FILE}
```

Comment: I think it's not possible with docker compose and yaml files all by themselves.
You might want to create some shellscripts or go program to achieve this.

Comment: Ok no worries, thanks! I'm current getting around it by mounting '/' from the docker host as read only - this probably isn't the best way to do it but it works as that contains all root files and drives in /mnt/

Comment: What are you actually trying to do, that you need more than about three volume mounts?

Comment: Backups; I have Duplicati running in docker, and I have my docker-compose.yml on GitHub and would like to make it as universal as possible, i.e. not hard-coding a load of file paths that might not be relevant to others

Answer (score 0):

Not specifically like you've requested, but you can merge multiple compose files together. One of those files could include your additional volumes while the first one is just your service definition. Your second file would look like:

```
version: '3'
services:
  name:
    volumes:
      - ${DIR1PATH}:/storage/${DIR1}
      - ${DIR2PATH}:/storage/${DIR2}
      - ${DIR3PATH}:/storage/${DIR3}
      - ${DIR4PATH}:/storage/${DIR4}
```

There are also extension fields in compose that allow you to define values, and then use yaml anchors and aliases to inject a value. An example of these are in [this presentation](https://sudo-bmitch.github.io/presentations/dc2019/tips-and-tricks-of-the-captains.html#16).

Comment: I see, is there a way to reference the second docker-compose file in the first, or would they both need to be passed as file arguments when running the docker-compose command? 

Ah that's really useful! Probably no closer than your other suggestion in this case however